# How to interface mbed with labview?

Tags: interface

How do I interface mbed with labview?
Do i first write the code with c then compile using keil and then put that same code on lab view or can I just use lab view directly?
I'm working on a sensor that is controlled by the mbed and the data has to be acquired by labview and also I'd like to drive leds using labview.

Comment: This has less to do with coding than it does with the specific protocols you choose to use to communicate between the labview computer and the sensor.  How to YOU plan to interface these two things?

Comment: I plan to use a usb for mbed lpc1768.

Comment: I have seen low level drivers in C called from Labview and the Drivers "written" in Labview. Both work well except you have to keep the C compiler and it's linker and compiler settings etc recorded just in case you have to modify the driver at a later date. For simplicity of version control and documentation I would keep everything in either Labview or C.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be a little late but I thought perhaps more people may need this information.

There are two ways that I see this can be done without too much effort. You may need to get familiar with serial communication to send and receive data (or commands) properly.

1) Using Serial communication on your mbed LPC1768 and LabVIEW.

On the LPC1768, use serial communication and make sure to select the USBTX and USBRX pins. This will setup a serial communication port on the USB (view the serial example in the mbed handbook found here: https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Serial).

On LabVIEW, the serial palette is found in the block panel under: Instruments I/O --> Serial. Make sure you configure the serial port just like on the mbed and then you can just read and send data back and forth. (It's a bit more complex than this, this is just a brief summary as there are many resources available for serial communication in LabVIEW.)

2) mbed LabVIEW library.

A simpler solution would be to use mbed library for LabVIEW, found here: https://developer.mbed.org/cookbook/Interfacing-with-LabVIEW
Make sure you have installed correctly both the NI-VISA driver (can be found on National Instruments website as well) and the mbed library. After this, you could simply use the mbed library blocks within LabVIEW to configure serial port and read from the analog input and toggle the digital pins to control the LEDs you need.

Hopefully this gets you in the right direction!